# How to deal with "lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError"?

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-crawler, lxml

When I use `lxml.etree` to parse some page, it occurs errors like following

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Double hyphen within comment: <!--[if lte IE 9 ]>
```

the page's head code is like

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie6 domain_so"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie7 domain_so"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie8 domain_so"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9 domain_so"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="w3c domain_so"><!--<![endif]-->
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Whats wrong with the standard libraries `xml.etree.ElementTree`?

Comment: If you are parsing HTML, try `lxml.html` instead of `lxml.etree`.